# string query params getting converted to array

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, body-parser, query-string

I'm getting a problem in some nodejs servers where string query params get parsed into an array instead of being kept as a string. So something like this `https://somedomain.com/test?first=val&token=secret` will get parsed on the nodejs server such that the value in `params.first` is `['val']` instead of `'val'` and the value in `params.token` is `['secret']` instead of `'secret'`. What's unusual is that I've seen this in unrelated nodejs servers. One is an aws lambda running in production and the other was a local dev server where I was using `express.js` with `bodyParser`. Different codebases for each one. In the past I've run into issues with the [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs/) package due to the way it parses arrays, but this problem seems totally unrelated and I can't seem to find a similar problem reported elsewhere. Does anyone have any ideas what's causing this behavior? Thanks! :)

Comment: What are you using to make the request?

Comment: @CascadiaJS when it happened on the local dev server I was using the [Firecamp](https://firecamp.io/) browser extension. When it happened in the aws lambda I was using a webview within a [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) app.

Comment: Do you have a way of viewing the network traffic, like [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler)? If you do, does the url that is used have commas or braces? like `https://somedomain.com/test?first=val,&token=secret,`? That would cause it to be an array. There are many ways it could end up an array though. Here's a good explanation [Arrays in query params](https://medium.com/raml-api/arrays-in-query-params-33189628fa68)

Comment: Thanks for that. Just read the linked article and indeed one of those was the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out that the problem was the url had the same query param multiple times, and the [querystring](https://github.com/Gozala/querystring/) package handles this by creating an array with each value. The package is deprecated so I switched to the recommended [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) alternative, and I fixed the duplication problem in the url.